# Wher do Beta comes from?

Tags: transistors, bjt

I've never seen any explanation for why is the Collector current = Beta * Base current. Please if you know give me some derivation for it. No matter if it involves math or something higher level stuff.

Comment: It depends on doping. You may get a good answer at the physics site.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, when faced with a complicated system, it helps to find ways to simplify it, so that it's easily usable.

When we take a transistor connected in common emitter, and measure the base and collector currents, we notice a rough proportionality. It varies down a bit at very high currents, and very low currents. However, over several orders of magnitude, for reasonable currents like 1 uA to 10 mA (for small signal transistors) it's pretty close to constant. It's sufficiently constant that it's worth giving a name to, and it's called beta.

Answer (score 1):

Bipolar junction transistors have thin base layer, so thin that the thermal random motion causes substantial random jumps to the motion of the carriers. There can well be a +voltage in the base wire pulling electrons but the thermal random motion is so large that most of the electrons which come from the emitter drift to the collector which is much bigger target to hit than the miniscule base wire. If for one electron sucked by the base wire 100 electrons meet the collector we say "the current gain is 100" .

As others have already said the current gain is not constant. It depends on currents and voltages. Circuits are designed so that they work when the current gain varies in certain limits.

You are in a hopeless situation if you still try to find a proof for an extreme simplification. Detailed description what exactly happens in a transistor needs something much more complicated math.

Most of us are practical electricians, which can get much work done by assuming the major part of the electrons (for ex. 99 percents or more) which come from emitter to base go to collector. That assumption actually isn't especially vague because the manufacturer gives some limits for the current gain and can even give some curves how the current gain depends on voltages, currents and the temperature.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking why "collector current=beta * base current" .
Well, this is a mathematical form that does not reflect the way this relation was found. 
In fact, one has discovered that the RATIO between the collector current Ic and the emitter current Ie is pretty constant and very close to (but always smaller than) unity: **Ic=alpha*Ie**.

Now - because of **Ie=Ic+Ib** it is very simple to show that **Ic=[alpha/(1-alpha)]*Ib.**

We define now  **[alpha/(1-alpha)]=beta** and we arrive at the ratio **Ic/Ib=beta**.

Because alpha is a parameter that can be considered as nearly constant over a pretty large range of emitter currents, the same applies to the parameter beta.

(In this context, it should be mentioned that some people (and some textbooks) think that this relation would mean that Ib would determine resp. control the amount of Ic. But this is another question that was discussed extensively elsewhere...also in this forum).

Answer (score 0):

It's not derived. It's an empirical observation and kind of a hand-wavey one too since is not constant, but variable. Now if you are asking the physics between how a small base current acts to produce a larger collector current, that's a different question.

This question might be indicative of a misunderstanding of science of physics or models. Things can only be mathematically derived based on a set of assumptions or models, and those assumptions and models themselves are based on more empirical observation, and it just keeps going back and back like that. So if you're looking for something like a pure math derivation that kind of comes out of nowhere and explains why something is the way it is, then you're not going to find one. It's more like "we stumbled upon this math or model that seems to, more or less, predict and match what we observe so we use it."

This is a lot more obvious in fields where we know the the math is not very correct like aerodynamics at small scales and low speeds where we try to apply math to try and predict things and it only kinda sorta works and you can't even really say that it is roughly accurate because it doesn't match what we observe most of the time and we don't know why. Or perhaps, most famously, the the attempt unify relativity with quantum mechanics. You try to apply math from one field to another and it just doesn't work.

It's a bit like asking how to derive F=ma. You can't really. It's an empirical observation. Sure, you can derive F=ma by using approximations and simplifying equations from Relativity, but then Relativity is also just a mathematical model we use because it happens to match empirical observation. It doesn't really come from anywhere. It, and everything more fundamental that it is based on is ultimately just something math, models, and explanations that humans stumbled across that seems to accurately predict and match our observations.

So in physics (and even in math if you go deep enough) when you simply ask "how do I derive something?" you have to be more specific about the context or scope and what it is you are actually looking for (i.e. how deep you want to go) because just asking that points to this misunderstanding of how we know what we know.

Comment: I'm asking for physics, i don't want to argue but i really well understand physics and math. It's not like asking F=m*a because that is the axiomatic nature of what we observe the reality, but till i don't ask for Maxwell's equations, or classical or quantum mechanics, there must be a derivation for a complex system just like transistors, that we create ourselves. If not exact derivation, maybe a numerical solution-like derivation.

Comment: @BálintTatai No, F=ma is not axiomatic. It is a simplified form of a more accurate equation. https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Modern_Physics/Book%3A_Spiral_Modern_Physics_(D%27Alessandris)/2%3A_The_Special_Theory_of_Relativity_-_Dynamics/2.1%3A_Relativistic_Momentum%2C_Force_and_Energy Anways, you may be barking up the wrong tree with beta anyways since it is so variable. Maybe what you are looking for is the charge control model?

Comment: I think that physics at the lowest level is such a phylosophic, that you can't say what is really going on in the world as axiomatic, rather everyone can have their own interpretation that the basic axioms are symmetries, or lagrange mechanics or other mechanics or kinda string and field theories. Anyway thanks for the charge control model tip. I learn EE (bsc) but i want physical approach of engineering, and at the university, they don't want to teach students normally to really understand technology.